# Set volume using php exec and amixer

Tags: apache-http-server, php, alsa, exec

I wrote a little php script to control the volume of my local machine with alsa:

```
<?php
# for simplicity and testing it really just executes the command:
echo exec('amixer set Master 5%+') . " \n";
```

Now when I run this script on command line it works fine:

```
$ php volume.php 
Front Right: Playback 39226 [60%] [on] 
$ php volume.php 
Front Right: Playback 42503 [65%] [on] 
$ php volume.php 
Front Right: Playback 45780 [70%] [on]
```

I have music playing and I hear it getting louder.

But when I try to run the script via apache from the browser calling `http://localhost/volume.php` it doesn't work.

```
# http://localhost/volume.php
Front Right: Playback 55709 [10%] [on]
# F5
Front Right: Playback 55709 [15%] [on]
# F5
Front Right: Playback 55709 [20%] [on]
```

Now I hear no change in volume and the percentages seem to be unrelated to the current state. It says 10% - 15% - 20% when it really is still at 70%.

My apache is running as my user so `exec('whoami')` gives me the username I am logged in with on my shell where everything works fine.

```
# httpd.conf
User mkt
Group mkt
```

I'm on Fedora 22.

Probably it's due to the apache2 process environment.
Any ideas how to fix this?

**UPDATE**:

This is the output of aplay -L:

```
[mkt@localhost ~]$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
```

On command line only default and pulse are working:

```
amixer -D pulse set Master 5%+
amixer -D default set Master 5%+
```

With PHP even those two don't work.
Anyway... my sound comes from my monitors speakers which is plugged in via hdmi. So I guess the last 4 devices are my candidates. But non of them work.

```
$ amixer -D hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0 set Master 5%+
$ amixer -D hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1 set Master 5%+
$ amixer -D hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2 set Master 5%+
$ amixer -D hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3 set Master 5%+
```

In all four cases it says:
(with DEV=[0-3] of course)

```
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
amixer: Mixer attach hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3 error: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**

Output of aplay -l:

```
$ aplay -l

**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sub-Devices: 0/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Sub-Devices: 1/1
  Sub-Device #0: subdevice #0

$ amixer -c0 set Master 5%+
$ amixer -c1 set Master 5%+
```

Both don't work!

Comment: What would be helpful is your apache logs, they'll likely tell you what's wrong immediately. or you could log this directly to the page too via various means.

Comment: Since your default is pulse, why not use it? i.e.: `pactl set-sink-volume 0  0% 
pactl set-sink-volume 0  100%
pactl set-sink-volume 0 -- +10%
pactl set-sink-volume 0 -- -10%
`

Comment: In both cases you need to set the environment variable PULSE_SERVER: `putenv("PULSE_SERVER=/run/user/".getmyuid()."/pulse/native");`.

Comment: @piernov Nailed it! Post this as an answer and I will accept it. Maybe you also want to post it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867273/set-volume-using-php-exec-and-amixer